# How can I draw geometric shapes in my question?

Tags: support, mathjax

I am not familiar with MathJax format. Can I draw simple geometric shapes in my question, without uploading a picture?

Comment: It would be better if you deleted this and asked on [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead. They have a mathjax tag there.

Comment: There's [a comprehensive(?) tutorial about MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on [Meta.Math.SE]

Comment: okay thanks , i get it

Comment: Since MathJax is supported on multiple sites, not just Mathematics.SE, it's (IMO) on-topic for Meta.SE.

Answer (score 8):

No, not really. MathJax is primarily built to display mathematical *equations*, not mathematical *pictures*. They don't explicitly state it's not supported, but they do state the following about their [Core Goals](https://www.mathjax.org/#about):

> Our key design goals are:
>
> - High-quality display of mathematics *notation* in all browsers.

(emphasis mine)

Note that even richer markup languages like TeX have to rely on packages/plugins like [TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) to draw pictures.

Now, it *might* be possible to 'abuse' certain MathJax features to output some kind of drawing. However, it's a lot easier to just pick a tool which is meant for drawing. Some helpful resources can be found in the links mentioned under this question: [Is there a standard drawing tool used for asking or answering questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21386/228959)